# MQTT+Openhab: Command Line works but Mqtt-Binding not

Tags: raspberry-pi, mqtt, esp8266, openhab

**My setup:**

- RaspberryPi with openhabian + mqtt-broker
- Esp8266 NodeMCU (mqtt client)

I have added an `mqtt-broker` with `openhabian-config` and downloaded the `mqtt-binding` via Paper UI. Additionally I was already able to power On & Off an output called `Catflap` via terminal using the following code:

```
mosquitto_pub -d  -t "openhabian/feeds/onoff" -m "ON"
```

and

```
mosquitto_pub -d  -t "openhabian/feeds/onoff" -m "OFF"
```

---

**Issue:**

Anyhow if I try to add a switch into the Items File it does not publish anything. I have been using MqttFX to check.

Here are my settings:

- **`mqtt.cfg`**

  The only statement in the mqtt config

  ```
  # URL to the MQTT broker, e.g. tcp://localhost:1883 or ssl://localhost:8883
  #<broker>.url=tcp://<host>:1883
  broker.url=tcp://localhost:1883
  ```
- **Item File**

  ```
  // This is the Items File
  // Catflap
  Switch CatFlap "Katzenklappe" ["Switchable"] {mqtt=">[broker:openhabian/feeds/onoff:command:ON:ON],>[broker:openhabian/feeds/onoff:command:OFF:OFF]" }
  ```